# ie9 rounded corner rendering little dots

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-9

So I am getting a weird rendering deally in ie9

[image]

You see those little white dots on the left? What the #$@# are they? How can I get rid of them?

Microooossooofffttt !?!?! *rings clenched hands at sky

Here is the css that makes this cute little button:

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    background: #356BB1;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

By the way, sometimes these dots don't show up, but they always do after the button position is animated. Also I am running ie9 in vmware fusion, so that might be useful info.

Thanks folks!

Comment: Looks fine ti me: http://jsfiddle.net/MBjNc/

Comment: IE9 (64 bit) on Win7 looks fine here. Your screenshot looks like artifacts from a bad video driver.

Comment: this is hardly microsoft's fault. @j08691 is probably correct, your video driver just sucks.

Comment: Fair enough, if its just an issue with the vmware virtual video card messing up then I don't care. The first one of you three to state this in an answer wins 25 points. Go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 (64 bit) on Win7 looks fine here. Your screenshot looks like artifacts from a bad video driver.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that usually happens on VM's environments, something related to the video card, I had the same problem while looking at the VM and didn't have the issue on a native Windows 7 / IE9